# How can I install the package 'tabulizer'?

Tags: r, tabulizer

I need to work with the "tabulizer" library in R but when installing the package it shows me the following message: "Installing package into 'C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/R/win-library/4.1'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
package 'tabulizer' is not available for this version of R".
Has anyone been able to fix this problem?

Comment: You likely need to update R.

Comment: Please check readme https://github.com/ropensci/tabulizer - requirements for Java on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The package [has been archived on CRAN](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/tabulizer/index.html) due to [issues with Java](https://github.com/ropensci/tabulizer/issues/140). For the time being, you can’t install it using `install.packages`.

As an alternative you can use [‘pak’](https://github.com/r-lib/pak), [‘remotes’](https://cran.r-project.org/package=remotes) or similar to install it, e.g.:

```
pak::pkg_install('ropensci/tabulizer')
```